# I have an issue in my .htaccess file related to SEO friendly URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using RewriteRule for seo friendly URL its working fine but when I load project in browser its open `search.php` file instead of `index.php` file. My `.htaccess` file is below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]

#Adjust default time zone
SetEnv TZ America/Washington

ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/estate2/404

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ <YourRelativePathToPHPFile>/404.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/search.php/$
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)?$ search.php?type=$1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for showing your htaccess file. Could you please do let us know what is the logic you want to show index.php even if search.php is present in your backend? Because one of your rule is doing that, so what should be Logic or conditions to show files or serve thins by index.php? Kindly elaborate here more.

Comment: In menu I am using  <a href="house-for-sale">House for Sale</a> so I got house-for-sale in $_GET and I am using $_GET['type'] = house-for-sale for get data from database in search.php file

Comment: So you mean you are trying to send value as a query string? Kindly do mention sample URLs like what URL which will in front end and how you want it to get served in back-end(sample URLs only) for better understanding.

Comment: this is URL : http://localhost/estate2/house-for-sale and I want to redirect it to search.php file actually its working but when I use  http://localhost/estate2 its directly open search.php file I want if there is  http://localhost/estate2/house-for-sale then it go to the search.php and if there is  http://localhost/estate2 it will open index.php file

Comment: Ok so only for house-for-sale your url you want it to fo to search.php not anything else right? Just want to confirm once.

Comment: yes thats right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples. Please clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. I have added 2 rules for `search.php` thing rest rules are from OP's shown .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/estate2/(house-for-sale)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ search.php?type=%1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]

#Adjust default time zone
SetEnv TZ America/Washington

ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/estate2/404

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ <YourRelativePathToPHPFile>/404.php [L]
```